# Using "eval" in a couchdb reduce - just how dangerous is this?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, mapreduce

My docs contain lists of errors.
I have a view which counts the number of docs with a specific error, and an average of how many errors a doc with a given error has.

Map

```
function (doc) {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < doc.errors.length; i = i + 1){
    emit([doc.errors[i], doc.flummery], [1, doc.errors.length])
}
```

}

Reduce

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
var avg = [];
var cnt = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < values.length; i = i + 1) {
    avg.push(values[i][1]);
    cnt.push(values[i][0]);
}
return [sum(cnt), eval(avg.join("+")) / avg.length]
```

}

I have read many times that the use of eval() is the path to madness, but I can't think of any way that it could really trip me up here. Is eval() safe in couchdb views?

Note that Oleg came up with the obvious answer, which is "don't do that, couchdb gives you a sum() function". It is obvious in this situation that eval() is not needed. However, should I ever require it, is it safe to use given that I'll have good control over my inputs?

Comment: The same code could be done without `eval()` and `join()`. That way you don't need to think about nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use `sum(avg) / avg.length` instead?

`eval` have obvious drawback of calling full power of compiler: it is very resource heavy and introduces a big security hole unless you carefully sanitize your input.

Comment: *facepalm* Yes, I sure could. And I will.
I guess the question still stands, though: If there *is* a situation where eval() could be called, is it safe here, since we have pretty good control over our inputs?

Comment: `eval` _could_ be called anywhere, but there's pretty much always more lightweight way to do it.

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks Oleg.